# Umbraco 7 dependeyhandler.axd typeerrror

Tags: dependencies, typeerror, umbraco7

When loading Umbraco dependeyhandler.axd throws an error "propertyAlias must be a string".
Then, when I try to publish some content, no matter what, dependencyhandler.axd throws another error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined"

In another content node it throws this error
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined"

When I hit F5 to reload the current node, then publishing works fine.

When leaving the "Content" area, moving to the "Media" area and back. The same issues appear again.

Any help would be appriciated.

With regard.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I cured the exact same problem (v7.2.4):

A collegue found this possible fix/workaround in `\Umbraco\js\umbraco.services.js` This function loops through the array and then through some methods which seems to be causing grief. `var cb` is numeric up to 32 (in my case) then becomes `"shuffle"` and that throws the error in the first post.

```
reset: function () {
        this.clear();
        for (var cb in callbacks) {
            callbacks[cb].callback.apply(this, [
                    true,       //pass in a value indicating it is VALID
                    [],         //pass in empty collection
                    []]);       //pass in empty collection
        }
},
```

has been changed to:

```
reset: function () {
        this.clear();
        for (var cb=0; cb<callbacks.length; cb++) {
            callbacks[cb].callback.apply(this, [
                    true,       //pass in a value indicating it is VALID
                    [],         //pass in empty collection
                    []]);       //pass in empty collection
        }
},
```

And now it seems to be working.